# zf3 translate route - translator not found

Tags: routes, zend-framework3

I need to realize a multilanguage site. Than i need to use i18n and translator but I've some problem with route translator

This is my module.config.php

```
{
return [
    'router' => [
        'router' => [
            'router_class'           => TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack::class,
        ],
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'application' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/{contact}',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]};
    }
```

And this is my Module.php class

```
 public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        /** @var \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator $translator */

        $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator');
        $translator->addTranslationFilePattern(
            'phpArray',
            Resources::getBasePath(),
            Resources::getPatternForValidator()
        );
        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
    }
```

When I start application I got this error

```
Zend\Router\Exception\RuntimeException: No translator provided in ..vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\Http\Segment.php on line 372
```

How can I pass translator to segment class? I need to use different class for translate?

Comment: Do you have both `Zend\I18n`, and `Zend\Mvc\I18n` modules added in your app config?

Comment: Yes are there. The problem was configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was configuration. I move this

```
'router' => [
        'router_class' => \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Router\TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack::class,
        'routes' => [

        ],
    ],
```

in global config and all work fine.